# ERROR:../../mono/io-layer/handles-private.h:362

Tags: c, debian

I execute my application in Debian 6 OS. From time to time there is an exception:

> ERROR:../../mono/io-layer/handles-private.h:362:_wapi_handle_share_release:
>   assertion failed: (info->handle_refs > 0) Stacktrace:
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.IO.MonoIO.Close
>   (intptr,System.IO.MonoIOError&) <0x00004>   at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native) System.IO.MonoIO.Close
>   (intptr,System.IO.MonoIOError&) <0x00004>   at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Dispose (bool) <0x00094>   at
>   System.IO.Stream.Close () <0x0001b>   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose ()
>   <0x00019>   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   System.IO.Stream.Dispose () <0x00053>   at
>   Sarum.Logger.Log.WriteToFile (Sarum.Logger.SLogMessage,bool) <0x0077d>
>   at Sarum.Logger.Log.WriteLineAsync () <0x00212>   at (wrapper
>   runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void_*this*_
>   (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00040>

**Native stacktrace:**

> /usr/bin/cli() [0x80d5b19]  [0xdf6600]  /lib/libc.so.6(abort+0x182)
>   [0x13d962]    /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_assertion_message+0x13f)
>   [0xc9232f]    /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x6198d) [0xc9298d]  /usr/bin/cli()
>   [0x81df0da]   /usr/bin/cli() [0x81e2d22]  /usr/bin/cli() [0x81e2eb6]
>     /usr/bin/cli() [0x8161dc0]  [0xa1c6f8]  [0xa1c625]  [0xa1c584]
>     [0xa1c752]  [0x5711ec]  [0x2c59ce]  [0x2c41b3]  [0x2832b1]
>     /usr/bin/cli() [0x8064428]  /usr/bin/cli(mono_runtime_invoke+0x40)
>   [0x812d4e0]   /usr/bin/cli(mono_runtime_delegate_invoke+0x34)
>   [0x812d764]   /usr/bin/cli() [0x81284bf]  /usr/bin/cli() [0x81f5e3e]
>     /usr/bin/cli() [0x82089a5]  /lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x57b0) [0x9857b0]
>     /lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e) [0x1dc0be]

**Debug info from gdb:**

> =================================================================
>   Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal
>   error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your
>   application.
>    =================================================================
>
> ** (/usr/local/bin/cserver/WadJet.CentralServer.exe:8141): WARNING **: process_set_termination_details: error looking up process handle 0x403

Why is this and how this can be combated?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of people who have reported similar errors that have plagued older versions of Mono.  You might first want to try out updating the Mono as suggested **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9715521/200272)**.